# Using MAX function for greatest value between a range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Pretty new to tsql functions, and I'm trying to write one that returns a value for the `STC_STATUS` for the greatest `STC_STATUS_DATE` where the `STC_STATUS_DATE is <= the STC_START_DATE+9`.  They way I have it now, it returns a null value if there is a `STC_STATUS > stc_start_date+9`.

```
  SELECT @Result1 = STC_STATUS
  FROM STC_STATUSES ss
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_ACAD_CRED stc ON ss.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID = stc.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID
  WHERE ss.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID = ISNULL(@student_acad_cred_id, '0') 
  AND MAX(ss.STC_STATUS_DATE) <= DATEADD(day,9,stc.STC_START_DATE)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  Sample data per recommendation:

[image]

The function returns a null value because pos 1 has a stc_status date that is greater than `stc_start_date+9`.  What I aim to have the function do is return the most recent status date below `stc_start_date+9`, which would be record 2 in this sample.

Comment: It would help if you add some sample data. Also add additional tag `SQL-Server-2008` or `SQL-Server-2012` for SQL version and to get additional exposure

Comment: Use Having Clause or subquery for Max(MAX(ss.STC_STATUS_DATE)) not in the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `TOP 1` to get the correct result

```
      SELECT TOP 1 @Result1 = STC_STATUS
      FROM  STC_STATUSES ss
      LEFT  OUTER JOIN STUDENT_ACAD_CRED stc 
            ON ss.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID = stc.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID
      WHERE ss.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID = ISNULL(@student_acad_cred_id, '0') 
            AND ss.STC_STATUS_DATE <= DATEADD(day,9,stc.STC_START_DATE)
      ORDER BY ss.STC_STATUS_DATE desc
```

Comment: I can't upvote yet but thank you for your help, this is exactly what I needed.